# iterate over properties of a php class

Tags: php, dynamic, variables

How can i iterate over the (public or private) properties of a php class?

Comment: You can even type-cast objects: `var_dump((array) $object);`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
// iterate public vars of class instance $class
foreach (get_object_vars($class) as $prop_name => $prop_value) {
   echo "$prop_name: $prop_value\n";
}
```

**Further Example:**

http://php.net/get_object_vars

> Gets the accessible non-static properties of the given object according to scope.

```
class foo {
    private $a;
    public $b = 1;
    public $c;
    private $d;
    static $e; // statics never returned

    public function test() {
        var_dump(get_object_vars($this)); // private's will show
    }
}

$test = new foo;

var_dump(get_object_vars($test)); // private's won't show

$test->test();
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["b"]=> int(1)
  ["c"]=> NULL
}

array(4) {
  ["a"]=> NULL
  ["b"]=> int(1)
  ["c"]=> NULL
  ["d"]=> NULL
}
```

Comment: So could i do a: 

foreach(get_object_vars($this) as $prop=>$val) 

?

Comment: yes, however only the public vars will be displayed, private ones are returned only when the caller of get_object_vars is inside the class.

Comment: Yep, as Lou said, <a href="http://nz.php.net/get_object_vars">get\_object\_vars</a> is the function you need.