# How do I iterate through a child's private fields?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, iteration, abstract-class

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861254/iterate-over-properties-of-a-php-class)
One idea for my problem was to implement the method in the child classes like:

```
class Child {
    private $childField = "Want to see";
    public $pubChildField = "Will see";

    public function method()
    {
        $assoc = []; // a associative array
        foreach ($this as $field => $value) {
            $assoc[$field] = doStuff($value);
        }
        return $assoc;
    }
}
var_dump((new Child())->jsonSerialize());
```

But for this I'd have to copycat the code in each child class. For readability, I want to refactor it into an (already existing) `parentClass` similar to:

```
abstract class parentClass {
    public function method()
    {
        $assoc = []; // a associative array
        foreach ($this as $field => $value) {
            $assoc[$field] = doStuff($value);
        }
        return $assoc;
    }
}
class Child extends parentClass {
    private $childField;
    public $pubChildField;
}
var_dump((new Child())->jsonSerialize());
```

Both `foreach ($this as $k=>$v)` and `get_object_vars()` will get the public fields from the instance. I need to get it's private fields thou, for serialization.

---

Edit 1: Typo abstract method - what was i thinking

Edit 2: Clarified the example

Edit 3: Reformulated the question since there seemed to be misconception

Comment: `obviously $this refers to the abstract method`.... No!!!! `$this` refers to the `instance`; `$this` never refers to a class

Comment: Why do you even want to do this, Janseen?

Comment: Here's the PHP manual with the basics for objects and classes in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php. Here's a bit more about Object Inheritance: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php. I think you should look through them.

Comment: edited for clarification - i hope the question is clearer now

Comment: You can use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), but, IMHO, the entire idea is terrible and should be scrapped.

Comment: If the parent class need to know it's children, you've done something wrong from the start.

Comment: the get_object_vars() results in the exact same: only access to public fields - should i rather implement the method for each child? which means just copy pasting it, since the implementation is identical and independent of class

Comment: What is the final goal? Why do you need to iterate over the object's properties?

Comment: The base class should not be aware of the classes that extends it. It should not even care about the fact that it is extended or not.

Comment: preparation for serialization (make image resources base64-JPG strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Abstract class is about abstract methods, not inherited. I assume these
   are not relevant to the problem (otherwise make it ordinary default/base class).
2. `private` limits visibility to concrete class - use `protected`
   instead.

It seems to me that you need only code reuse. You might reach for traits in this casse - traits becoming part of a class, and you can iterate private fields.

```
interface ArrayData {
    public function toArray(): array;
}

trait ToArray {
    public function toArray(): array {
        $assoc = []; // a associative array
        foreach ($this as $field => $value) {
            $assoc[$field] = $value;
        }
        return $assoc;
    }
}

class Foo implements ArrayData {
    use ToArray;

    private $childField = "Want to see";
    public $pubChildField = "Will see";
}

$foo = new Foo();

var_dump($foo->toArray());
```

Comment: hm... using protected seems to be the cleanest solution... accepting (even thou it doesn't solve the formulated question in the title)

Comment: @S.Janssen With traits you can reuse code and iterate private fields. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to declare the base class `implements` the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface and implement the [`JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) method in all children classes.

You can let it unimplemented in the base class to force all the children classes implement it or you can provide a default implementation (`return array();`) in the base class for the children classes that do not need to be serialized.

The implementation in each class should not iterate over the list of object properties. Usually, not all object properties must be serialized and the serializable properties are not born equal.

```
abstract class parentClass implements JsonSerializable {

    // You can remove this default implementation
    // to force all children class implement the method
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array();
    }
}

class childClass extends parentClass {
    private $childField;
    public $pubChildField;

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array(
            'field1' => $this->childField,
            'field2' => base64_encode($pubChildField),
            // etc ...
        );
    }
}

var_dump((new Child())->jsonSerialize());
```

Try to write code that is easier to read and understand. You will thank yourself later.