# PHP: Invoking function when setting public property

Tags: php

I have an object called reportPayment:

```
class reportPayment extends JournalListElement {

public $paymentType;
public $paymentNum;
public $paymentAmnt;
public $accID;
public $accDesc;

function setPaymentAmnt($paymentAmnt) {
    $this->paymentAmnt = MoneyHelper::centsToDollars($paymentAmnt);
}

function getPaymentAmnt() {
    return $this->paymentAmnt;
}

}
```

Another class iterates over the public properties of this object to write an XML file; through:

```
foreach ($object as $key => $value) { }
```

My problem is that I need `$paymentAmnt` to be only set through the setter here so that `centsToDollars()` function is invoked. This only works if I turn `$paymentAmnt` to a private property though, something that I can't afford as I'm iterating through the object properties.

In short what I need is a way to:

1. Make sure that `centsToDollars()` is invoked when setting `$paymentAmnt`
2. Make sure that `$paymentAmnt` can be seen from outside

**Edit**: Now its possible as has been answered by Michal to set it as private, and still access the property through the getter. Setting it to private means that I can't iterate on the properties of the objects which is very imp for me in this case though.
Is there a way to do this in Yii2/PHP?

Comment: Have you looked into reflection? You can list all properties of an object, even if they are private, with ReflectionClass::getProperties (https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php)

Comment: I think this is going to work. Can you put it as answer so that I accept it. This is going to help future visitors to this question (if there are any?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) you can iterate through object properties even if they are private:

```
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($reportPaymentObject);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED | ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    print $prop->getName() . "\n";
}
```

[Other examples here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861254/iterate-over-properties-of-a-php-class)

Answer (score 2):

Once you've declared property as public you cannot limit access to it so there is no way to force setting it through setter only.

But in Yii there is a way how to make property seem public even if it's not.

If your class `JournalListElement` inherits from \yii\base\BaseObject (most classes in Yii inherit from this) and if you have setter and getter declared as this

```
class ReportPayment extends JournalListElement
{
    private $paymentAmnt;

    public setPaymentAmnt($value)
    {
        ...
    }

    public getPaymentAmnt()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Then you can still access the `paymentAmnt` property as if it was public like this:

```
  $report = new ReportPayment();
  $report->paymentAmnt = 20;
  echo $report->paymentAmnt;
```

That's because in `\yii\base\BaseObject` there are implementations of `__set` and `__get` magic methods. When you try to access inaccessible property these method will call `setPropertyName()` or `getPropertyName()` if methods like that exist.

If the property is `private` you will still access it directly from within ReportPayment class. You will automatically access it throu getter/setter from outside of class or from the classes that extends ReportPayment.

If the property is `protected` you will access it directly from within ReportPayment and all classes that extends it. You will access it through getter/setter from outside of the ReportPayment class or its children.

In pure php you can get similar results by implementing [__set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) and [__get](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) methods by yourself.

**Iterating over properties**

You can use ReflectionClass to get list of all properties (private included) but I can't recommend doing it like that. Using this approach is against the principles of OOP and may cause problems later.
For example in situation where you need to add more private properties. In that case you will have to edit all your foreach cycles to skip the new properties.

Possible better approaches:

1) Method that returns array of visible properties:

```
class ReportPayment extends JournalListElement
{
    ... code declaring properties and getters/setters
    public function getProperties()
    {
        return ['paymentType', 'paymentNum', 'paymentAmnt', ...];
    }
}

foreach ($object->getProperties() as $prop) {
    echo $object->$prop;
}
```

2) Method that converts properties to array

```
class ReportPayment extends JournalListElement
{
    ... code declaring properties and getters/setters
    public function asArray()
    {
        return [
            'paymentType' => $this->paymentType,
            'paymentNum' => $this->paymentNum,
            'paymentAmnt' => $this->paymentAmnt,
            ...
        ];
    }
}

foreach ($object->asArray() as $prop => $value) {
    echo $prop . ": " . $value;
}
```

3) Implementing `Iterator` interface.
You can find [more details here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php).
 Own implementation of `Iterator` interface allows you to control what keys/values the foreach goes through.

The biggest advantage of these approaches is that the class itself still controls what properties the cycles goes through.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
My problem though is that I want to iterate through the properties of the object as foreach ($object as $key => $value) { }
This way its not visible

Comment: @mrateb I've edited my answer to add the ways how to deal with iterating over properties. ReflectionClass approach works but i don't recommend it.